# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement when installing webbrowser module . (Python)

Tags: python, installation, python-webbrowser

Trying to just install a module. Specifically the webbrowser module. I've had this problem come up a couple times but I was never able to fix it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The webbrowser module comes as part of the standard library in both [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) & [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html) so there's no need to install it using pip.

The best way to test to see if this module is working is to open up the python shell and run:

```
import antigravity
```

This is an Easter egg in the language that will use the `webbrowser` module to open a new browser tab that will open up a xkcd comic depicting the satirical usage of `import antigravity`

Hope this helps